# Class comes back after JQuery removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript to clone a div when the user clicks on a button. In the div to be cloned I have a child div with a class called `hidden`. When the clone happens I make a naked copy and remove the hidden class from the cloned div's child. It works fine, but if the user submits the page and it comes back with an error, for example, the clone has its hidden class added again.

Isn't it supposed to stay without this class since it was removed?

```
$(row).find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```

```html
<div class="6u 12u(narrower) hidden">
    <a id="delete" class="button alt small right delete">Slet</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya, submiting a `form` reload/redirect page. Use persistent data client side as sessionStorage or find other way to submit data,e.g using ajax. Now maybe, i completly misunderstood what is your question/issue....

Comment: So I have to find a way to store the information that the `div` was hidden?

Comment: But are you submiting a `form`? If ya, use instead ajax to submit data. Now anyway, you have to provide MCVE replicating your issue. Your question is quite unclear imho

Comment: What I am planning to do will not work with JavaScript. I will find another alternative to what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you have your line `$(row).find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");`, try calling this piece of code on the `onLoad()` of the page too

Comment: The problem is that if I do that then the form to be cloned will have its `hidden` div shown, which I don't want.

Comment: I think I don't get it. Create a function if necessary, but I think you should execute this code at the beginning. If the page reloads after an error, it will have to reclone the `form` and delete the `hidden` div.

Comment: The clone happens when the user clicks on a button to clone the form. So a new form comes up with the hidden class removed. However, when the page is submitted and comes back with an error, for example, the class I removed in the clone (hidden) also comes back.

Comment: Ok, that's because the browser comes back to the previous version of the page.
You will have to manage it on some way. I would tell you the same as before. When the page "starts", check if the **clone** exists and remove it, or remove the `hidden`, or whatever you want to do.

Comment: But what I am wondering is that I have other functions in this jQuery script that clones a lot of things. Aren't they supposed to vanish as well? I have a function to reindex the ids for the inputs. Shouldn't they also vanish?

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I can't tell you the reason why it happens. Maybe it does because other clones don't remove classes, can't know.
You can use what I've said below to do the trick, and wait if someone can clarify.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am thinking and it is my framework that replicates the form when it is submitted. I will have to work around the problem. Thanks for the help.